# Modify to fix context from patches to observer netlogo

Tags: netlogo

What are the general rules to convert a code from patches to observer context?
For example, if I have a code like this, how should I modify it to convert the button from patches to observer context?
`if numRed <= numYellow [set pcolor red]
if numYellow < numRed [set pcolor yellow]
if numGreen < numBlue [set pcolor green]`

Comment: Please actually look at the tag description before adding a tag. Many words in programming are used for multiple different meanings, but a tag is only for one meaning.

Answer (score 3):

There are no general rules as such. But the most common way to change contexts is with the primitive `ask`. Look at this code:

```
to testme
  ask n-of 10 patches
  [ set pcolor red
  ]
end
```

The procedure is in observer context. That is, it is written from the perspective of an outsider looking at the model. Then the `ask` randomly selects 10 patches. The code switches perspective (at the open square bracket) and sort of pretends it's the first of those randomly selected patches. That patch sets its color (`pcolor`) to red. Then the perspective switches to the second randomly selected patch. It also thinks to itself to change colour. While the code is running through those 10 patches, it is in patch context. The the close square bracket ends the code block, simultaneously ending the patch context and jumping back out to the observer context.

If your code is in patch context (or link context or turtle context), then you have to tell it which patches (or links or turtles) to be applying the code to. The default is all. Try this:

- open a new NetLogo model
- create a button: In the dialogue box for that button, use the dropdown box at the top to make it patches context. In the code box, type `set pcolor red`

Press the button and all patches will turn red.

I believe that a beginner in NetLogo should write every procedure from the observer context. This means that all the commands to patches and turtles are contained within clear `ask <agentset> [ <do something > ]` structures. It is easier for you to keep track of what you are doing and which model entities are doing it.

Comment: Hi JenB, I take my chance and comment here hoping for some insight in the observer/patch context. I running multiples procedure that call each others: `to start ask patches with [age = 65] [successor] end ` then `to successor ***some calculations with globals and patch-owns variables and *** if (successor-result = 1) [set age 18] end ` my idea is to set the age of the concerned patch (age = 65) to 18 but I get an error stating that the `successor` procedure is in patch context and I can't use it in observer context.

Comment: I'm confused because the successor procedure is indeed called from the go procedure in a patch context, so the command ´set age 18` should work for the patch context. Isn't it ?